# Google compute engine ssh - 255 timeout

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I am trying to ssh into gcloud compute instance.

This is the error I am getting when I run this:

```
gcloud compute ssh username@instance --ssh-flag="-v" --zone=us-east1-b

OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/username/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ip-address [ip-address] port 22.
debug1: connect to address  ip-address port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host  ip-address port 22: Connection timed out
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255]
```

It could be that instance is blocking this network

I tried telnet from local to instance.

```
telnet instance-ip-address 22
Trying instance-ip-address..
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
```

Could anyone help me on this.

**Note** : All ip-address mean actual ip-address of the instance.

Comment: Could you confirm that you have a firewall rule that allows TCP traffic to port 22?

Comment: Yes , port 22 is allowed in local and remote as well.

Comment: Please check if the OS firewall is not allowing the connection. Also some GCE images came with software like SSH guard that could block to many failed attempts.